# Google sheets built in charts style limitations

Tags: google-sheets, charts, candlestick-chart

I created a candlestick chart with the "insert chart" option of google sheets.

[image: candlestick chart]

Though, I noticed that there is no way to change the colors of the candlesticks and the border from there. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Welcome. If you *"noticed that there is no way to change..."*, then what is the question?

Comment: @marikamitsos I asked for another methods that I may not know and get the job done.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I don't think this is possible for embedded charts. I'd suggest you to request this feature via `Send feedback`. To do that, on the Sheets editor, click `Help > Help Sheets improve`.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank You